# Pinterest SDK binding for Monotouch - CreatePinWithImageURL crashes

Tags: c#, ios, sdk, xamarin.ios, pinterest

I'm trying to create bindings for the Pinterest SDK:

http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/

Most of the API works; `CanPinWithSDK` correctly returns `true` / `false` as expected.

But `CreatePinWithImageURL` always crashes. The top of the stack looks like this:

```
Feb  3 17:28:45 UK-IT-IPD-D0004 PinterestSDKDemo[8992] <Error>: Stacktrace:
Feb  3 17:28:45 UK-IT-IPD-D0004 PinterestSDKDemo[8992] <Error>:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
Feb  3 17:28:45 UK-IT-IPD-D0004 PinterestSDKDemo[8992] <Error>:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
Feb  3 17:28:45 UK-IT-IPD-D0004 PinterestSDKDemo[8992] <Error>:   at PinterestSDK.Pinterest.CreatePinWithImageURL (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl,string) [0x0005f] in /Users/Alasdair/code/PinterestSDKBinding/PinterestSDKBinding/obj/Debug/ios/PinterestSDK/Pinterest.g.cs:154
```

The binding looks like this:

```
[Export ("createPinWithImageURL:sourceURL:description:")]
void CreatePinWithImageURL (NSUrl imageURL, NSUrl sourceURL, string descriptionText);
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
[Export ("createPinWithImageURL:sourceURL:description:")]
[CompilerGenerated]
public virtual void CreatePinWithImageURL (NSUrl imageURL, NSUrl sourceURL, string descriptionText)
{
    if (imageURL == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("imageURL");
    if (sourceURL == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("sourceURL");
    if (descriptionText == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("descriptionText");
    var nsdescriptionText = NSString.CreateNative (descriptionText);

    if (IsDirectBinding) {
        MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr (this.Handle, selCreatePinWithImageURLSourceURLDescription_Handle, imageURL.Handle, sourceURL.Handle, nsdescriptionText);
    } else {
        MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, selCreatePinWithImageURLSourceURLDescription_Handle, imageURL.Handle, sourceURL.Handle, nsdescriptionText);
    }
    NSString.ReleaseNative (nsdescriptionText);

}
```

My app code looks like this:

```
Pinterest pinterest = new Pinterest ("1234", "prod");
NSUrl imageUrl = new NSUrl(@"http://static.bbci.co.uk/frameworks/barlesque/2.59.12/orb/4/img/bbc-blocks-dark.png");
NSUrl sourceUrl = new NSUrl(@"http://www.bbc.co.uk");
pinterest.CreatePinWithImageURL (imageUrl, sourceUrl, "description");
```

It crashes with no exceptions as soon as it hits `void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr`

I've set the client ID in my `info.plist` (copied from their demo app, which works fine in objective C).

Any ideas? Has anyone successfully created bindings for this SDK?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the PInterest library is buggy and your crash comes from here:

```
Pinterest pinterest = new Pinterest ("1234", "prod");
```

What happens is that PInterest keeps a copy of the `NSString` (the `System.String` are converted into them on demand) but it **does not** call `retain` on them. When you call the next API (that needs those values) then you get the crash (since they were released).

That's a bug - even in ObjC (if you keep a pointer reference to an `NSObject` it's your job/duty to retain it). Most ObjC applications likely don't hit this because they use `NSString` constants (fields that will never be freed) in their applications.

The workaround is to:

1. bind the `initWithClientId:urlSchemeSuffix:` API using `NSString` (instead of `string`);
2. keep the `NSString` instance for `"1234"` and `"prod"` alive (e.g. static fields) as long as your `pinterest` instance is needed.